# Using Fonts in your Applications

Tags: applications, fonts

When writing applications for software, specifically mobile devices, will there be a problem with using any specific type of fonts (copyright/patent issues)?

If so, how can we avoid this possible problems?

Will it then make a difference if the app was a paid version or a free version?

Comment: Also see http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/11397/1855

Answer (score 3):

That depends on the individual font and how it is encoded, then decoded into a human-readible glyph.

The shapes of the glyphs in fonts cannot be copyrighted.  If fonts could be copyrighted, then every printed text that was rendered in such a copyrighted font would be a derivative work.

However, the data files that encode fonts can be copyrighted.  If you bundle a font with your app, you have to take care to comply with any license terms under which that font is published.  If you buy a font for personal use from Adobe, you are not license to redistribute it.  I'm sure Adobe is happy to allow for redistribution, but to get licensed for that, you'll need to pay them a lot of money.

Many of the technologies for translating the font data files into the rendered glyphs that you see on-screen are patented.  That is not likely to be a problem for you on mobile devices, as the patent licensing is the responsibility of whoever is distributing the implementation of these font-rendering technologies.  That's usually the handset vendors.

You will only need to obtain patent licenses if you yourself provide the code that translates a font's data file into a screen glyph.  If you are using the type rendering engine that is built into your mobile device's operating system then you don't need to worry about the patents.

Note that source code is not considered to be an implementation of a patented technology.  Google doesn't have to pay any fees or obtain any licenses to distribute the Android sources.

That's up to the device vendors, as program binaries ARE considered implementations that are subject to the patent laws.  I suspect that many such vendors don't understand that, and that they all figure that Google has licensed all the patents that cover the Android codebase.  That would be the case if they were licensing a mobile OS in binary form, but it's not the case when they are just getting source code.

Comment: You're probably overthinking this.  All fonts come with a license agreement, stating in simple language how the font can be used.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using fonts that are licensed for commercial use. Some fonts cannot be widely used or distributed, depending on the licensing. Read the font license when purchasing or contact the author for information. This may apply to both free and paid fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Fonts are like songs; they are protected by copyright, and you need a license to use them.

If the font license is a free, unrestrictive license, then you probably won't have to pay money to use it.  If the font is already on someone's mobile device as part of the operating system installation, you shouldn't have to pay for a license.

If the font is a commercial font that requires you to pay a license fee to use it, then that's what you have to do.  Check the license agreement for the font; there should be sufficient information there to figure out what you need to do.

Comment: does this means that, for example if i were to create an application in an android tablet or phone, i can use any fonts that is installed on it, without any worries of legal issues? even if my application will be a paid one?

Comment: That's generally how it works. It's how web fonts work; you ask for Georgia, and if Georgia's not on the user's computer, it will fall back to something like Arial.

Comment: however, in situations where i will have to package the fonts i will require together with the application i will be developing (not installed with system) will i then have to pay a license fee or something?

Comment: It depends on the license agreement for the font. Read the license agreement; it will tell you how the font can be legally used.  Which font do you want to use?

Comment: I am actually trying to create a simple textbox in android that allows the user to selected a desired font from a list, hence, the best is that i can have as many fonts as possible for free.

Comment: The list should come from his device.  It's up to him where he gets his fonts.  You cannot redistribute those fonts to the user without a valid license.

Comment: but it seems that android has only provided a limited number of fonts [How to check Installed Fonts on Android Device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558866/how-to-check-installed-fonts-on-android-device) which doesn't fully cater to the look and feel of my application.

Comment: You're trying to get me to say that it's OK to install any font you want to; it isn't. :)  Many fonts are not free; you're going to have to decide for yourself if you want to pay for them or not.

Comment: haha, i was just wondering what's the limitations, to get the best i can without additional charge, since I am developing a trying to free app. It seems that it all comes down to going through the terms and conditions on the fonts that i interested in isn't it.

Answer (score 0):

The situation varies per jurisdiction. The font file itself (the binary .ttf, .otf, or whatever format it's in) is generally copyrightable pretty much everywhere in the world, and if you (digitally) convert it to a different format, you are creating a derived work, which is also covered by the original copyright.

The font design itself, however, is a slightly different story. In some jurisdictions, font designs are not considered works of art and are thus not subject to copyright; in others, they are. So if you make a font from scratch that looks like, say, Adobe Garamond, but isn't derived from the actual Adobe Garamond, you may or may not be subject to copyright claims.

And then there's trademarks, another form of intellectual property protection. Again, some jurisdictions allow trademarking entire fonts, others allow trademarking individual glyphs (which gets pretty damn expensive for entire unicode fonts), yet others disallow it altogether.

The safest (and probably wisest) thing to do is to obey the license that comes with the fonts you're using, use a free font ([fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) is full of them), or not embed any fonts yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Fonts are the font SOFTWARE (the actual .ttf or .otf file)

Just like Microsoft Office, only tiny.

Taking a font file and putting/embedding it in software, hardware, on a server, using it with @font face all requires a license fee

Taking the letterforms produced by a font like a .bmp or .jpg or any static picture of text is covered under the general EULA for $30 online at fonts.com, myfonts.com, linotype.com

When shipping the font in your app or serving it up on a server that's where you need an offline license that can cost thousands